# Metric to compute and compare RAM and CPU usage in Android

Tags: performance, memory-management, benchmarking, cpu-usage, android-source

I have two versions of Android that I'm testing on a device, both differ in few services in AOSP. I wanted to take some sort of a bench mark test to see how much the new system services are consuming my RAM and CPU usage. I'm not sure how to begin with. Are there any existing benchmarks that achieve the same? If not how should I proceed in this case.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could run some of my CPU and memory benchmarks (free, no adds) via

http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/android%20benchmarks.htm

Also, you could install Android Terminal Emulator from Google Play and use Linux commands for top or vmstat to monitor resources used (at least they work on my tablet).

Below are details from vmstat whilst running one of my benchmarks.

```
Command vmstat -d 1 -n 60 > /mnt/extsd/vmst3.txt
For 60 samples of one second to txt file on external SD card
via path as identified by the df command
Command cat /mnt/extsd/vmst3.txt to display details

Start this, switch to main display, execute MemSpeed.apk that uses up
to 65 MB over nearly 11 seconds (starts in 16 seconds after a bit of 
fiddling that uses some system CPU time). Note free memory reduction 
and 99% CPU utilisation for 10+ seconds. Idle time is clearly wrong.


procs  memory                       system          cpu              
 r  b    free mapped   anon   slab    in   cs  flt  us ni sy id wa ir
 0  0  909092 124948 197812  17600   365  554    0   3  0  2 99  0  0
 1  0  906052 124704 200544  17600  2176 3162    0  21  0 27 99  0  0
 0  0  905968 125700 200660  17596  1175 4000    0  15  0 21 99  0  0
 0  0  905968 125716 200672  17596   286  397    0   1  0  2 99  0  0
 0  0  905968 125716 200672  17596  1528 1226    0   5  0  6 99  0  0
 0  0  905160 124944 201276  17596  1533 4771    0  30  0 31 99  0  0
 0  0  905224 124944 201288  17596   349  460    0   3  0  4 99  0  0
 0  0  904588 125440 201984  17596  2721 6542    0  32  0 30 99  0  0
 0  0  903844 124964 202820  17596  2266 3569    0  25  0 17 99  0  0
 3  0  903720 126456 202860  17596  1924 6185    0  37  0 37 99  0  0
 1  0  897768 126504 202228  17596  2281 3661    0  29  0 20 99  0  0
 0  0  894296 134684 202308  17596  1437 4258    0  18  0 21 99  0  0
 0  0  894296 134700 202308  17596   521  631    0   4  0  7 99  0  0
 1  0  894296 134700 202308  17596   300  420    0   1  0  3 99  0  0
 0  0  894296 134700 202308  17596   320  417    0   0  0  4 99  0  0
 2  0  846820 142512 205780  17596  2273 3369    0  38  0 37 99  0  0
 0  0  846764 142492 205836  17616  1044 3101    0  23  0 21 99  0  0
 1  0  838960 142492 205804  17616  1661  974    0  49  0  8 99  0  0
 1  0  838960 142500 205908  17616   540  464    0  99  0  0 99  0  0
 1  0  838836 142504 205924  17616   515  444    0  99  0  0 98  0  0
procs  memory                       system          cpu              
 r  b    free mapped   anon   slab    in   cs  flt  us ni sy id wa ir
 1  0  838836 142504 205960  17616   521  442    0  99  0  1 99  0  0
 1  0  838712 142504 206140  17616   458  348    0  99  0  0 99  0  0
 1  0  838464 142504 206392  17616   479  373    0  99  0  0 99  0  0
 1  0  837968 142504 206900  17616   598  646    0  99  0  1 99  0  0
 1  0  834992 142504 209900  17616   688  772    0  99  0  2 96  0  0
 1  0  823088 142504 221928  17616   500  484    0  98  0  4 97  0  0
 1  0  774852 142504 269888  17616   447  366    0  95  0  6 97  0  0
 1  0  774852 142504 269900  17616   391  315    0  99  0  1 98  0  0
 0  0  774852 142504 269900  17616   401  477    0  51  0  4 99  0  0
 0  0  774728 142504 269932  17616   231  240    0   0  0  1 99  0  0
 0  0  774728 142504 269932  17616   219  239    0   0  0  0 99  0  0
 0  0  774728 142504 269932  17616   214  243    0   0  0  1 99  0  0
 0  0  774728 142504 269932  17616   196  222    0   0  0  0 99  0  0
 0  0  797028 144488 270676  17616  2621 6371    0  40  1 35 99  0  0
 0  0  797092 144560 270768  17612   466  801    0   1  0  7 99  0  0
 1  0  796564 146172 271020  17648  1548 1657    0  14  0  7 99  0  0
 1  0  796500 144044 271088  17648  1157 2890    0  10  0 12 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   367  503    0   2  0  4 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   343  438    0   2  0  4 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   275  348    0   3  0  3 99  0  0
procs  memory                       system          cpu              
 r  b    free mapped   anon   slab    in   cs  flt  us ni sy id wa ir
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   227  274    0   0  0  1 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   300  363    0   2  0  2 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   273  344    0   1  0  1 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   238  284    0   0  0  2 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   311  344    0   3  0  5 99  0  0
 1  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   246  289    0   1  0  0 99  0  0
 1  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   263  322    0   2  0  2 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   275  335    0   2  0  2 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   442  460    0   1  0  4 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   451  417    0   3  0  7 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   284  345    0   2  0  1 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   310  375    0   1  0  2 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271096  17648   278  339    0   1  0  2 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271100  17648   282  350    0   2  0  1 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271100  17648   242  284    0   2  0  2 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271100  17648   293  352    0   1  0  2 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271100  17648   343  511    0   8  0  2 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271120  17648   198  221    0   0  0  1 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271120  17648   227  263    0   0  0  0 99  0  0
 0  0  796564 144044 271120  17648   230  246    0   1  0  2 99  0  0
```